# How to create optGroup from multiselect (selectList)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-select

Q: How can I create optGroups within a [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic) given the following:

Model (pseudo):

```
class Area {
  string Name;
  string Id;
  string GroupId;   // Want to group by this and display opt groups with my multiselect.
}
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.AreaList = new SelectList(db.Areas.OrderBy(x => x.Name), "AreaId", "Name");
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBox("AreaList", null) 

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#AreaId").multiselect({
    selectedText: "Selected: #",
    minWidth: 210,
    noneSelectedText: "",
    selectedList: 1
});
</script>
```

Resulting HTML (example):

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value ="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value ="2">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value ="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value ="4">Option 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select>
@foreach (var group in Model.AreaList.select(new {group:GroupID}).Distinct())
{
    <optgroup>@group</optgroup>
    @foreach(var item in Model.AreaList.Where(r=>r.GroupID == group))
    {
         <option value="@id">@Name</option>
    }
}
```